# How to create a repeatable xml form field feature?

Tags: component, joomla-3.2

I am building a custom component and all is good. I thought I would have a go at the new 3.2 repeatable xml form field feature. Although I have it working I don't quite know how to save the data.

It allows me to launch a modal and within that modal create up to 999 custom fields that I specify. But the green save button in the modal closes the modal and doesn't actually apply the save?

Am I missing something?

--

```
<field name="list_templates"
    type="Repeatable"
    icon="list"
    description="Main description"
    label="Main Label"
    default="">
    <fields name="params">
    <fieldset hidden="true" name="list_templates_modal" repeat="true">
            <field name="template"
                    label="Template Label"
                    size="30"
                    type="text" />
            <field name="location"
                    label="Location Label"
                    description="desc"
                    size="30"
                    type="filelist"
                    directory="media/editors/tinymce/templates"
                    exclude="index.html"
                    hide_default="true"
                    hide_none="true" />
            <field name="description"
                    label="Description Label"
                    size="30"
                    type="textarea" />
    </fieldset>
    </fields>
```

Cheers in advance

Jonny

Comment: I believe there is still a bug with the repeating form fields. Closing then reopening the modal cause duplicate entries, however you may have found another bug. Mights be worth looking into

Comment: @Lodder ok cool. I just wish they added more details to the docs. I cant seem to find anything with more details. Its almost like you have to write extra code within the MVC for it to work.

Comment: @Lodder can you suggest another way to add repeatable fields within my component edit.php file?

Comment: There is no other easy way of doing it. Please provide the current code you're using for the repeating form fields

Comment: @Lodder sorry got distracted by my son coming in and telling me he assisted two soccer ( Football! ) goals to win the game. Under 10's good work. Anyway i have adjusted my post and maybe we can figure this one out together.

Comment: @Lodder i got it! - silly me didnt actually add the column name within the custom table component. So i added list_templates ( TEXT ) within the PHPMYADFMIN table and tested it again. It saved the data and evey new entry i added inside that MYSQL ( TEXT ) column as json. Now i can see though that there is that bug you speak of LOL. Bugger!

Comment: @Lodder can i mark my own question as solved? to help others? i have worked out the process and also fixed the duplicate entries bug. It was on line 32 of the repeatable.js file. Simply removing .clone() from the end of getTrs() fixed it. I have saved and closed and cancelled and saved and reopened several times checking the database as well as the modal and its working like its supposed to.

Comment: @Jonnypixel Can you please post the solution as a stand-alone answer?

Comment: If you were able to solve a bug I really hope you are reporting it on the joomla bug tracker so it can be fixed in the next release.

Comment: @ChadWindnagle ok cool. Frankly i have never signed up for the bug tracker as im not sure how much time i have but i know it would be only fair to do so. I just had a look around at how all that bug tracking works. It looks like a maze of links to and fro acros like 3 or 4 websites. Feel free to submit anything i have written if you like. Im so sorry but i just dont know where to start with those bug tracker, docs, pages, forums, githubs etc...

Comment: @ValentinDespa followed your advice :)

Comment: There are a lot more than a few bugs with repeatable fields.  Only certain field types work (standard radio, text, textarea, etc.  Nothing with a modal).

Answer (score 6):

Ok here is the answer to my own question and a couple of observations and fixes.

Firstly when using the sample block of code within my custom xml component file I neglected to add the field name within my custom database table.

So for example: list_templates from the xml example

Needs to go into the MYSQL database within my component table like so:

column name: list_templates 
column type: TEXT

Basically because its JSON data and it fits best inside a TEXT type column.

Next...

There was the bug where when closing teh Modal and then re-opening it would duplicate the content you add.

To fix this I found the repeatable.js file located within media/system/js and made a backup copy of it. I then pasted the uncomplressed version into repeatable js and found that by changing this line:

```
30 // Set original content for cancel            
31 origContent = getTrs().clone();
```

to this

```
30 // Set original content for cancel            
31 origContent = getTrs();
```

That it actually fixes the duplication bug. I have done several tests to see if its doing the right thing and it actually is. No data loss is occurring and no data is being duplicated anymore. You can open and close the modal box as many times as you like and it will only ever show you the selections you saved.

I have tried this by closing the view file and reopening the data as well and several other methods all of which are working.

And lastly!

Because I wanted to echo the contents of the JSON within my view as a table below the select button I also added a couple of things to repetable/js to allow me to be able to save and apply after clicking the save button within the modal.

This means that when I click save on trghe repeatable fields modal the page saves and applies allowing me to collect the data directly from teh table column field to display on the page.

I achieved this by adding the following couple of things.

A function to get the view=componentnameview from the url

```
 // get the url values function

 function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,    
    function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
  }
```

and then setting a varibale for view like so

```
var componentName = getUrlVars()["view"];
```

and then after line 341

I added this

```
Joomla.submitbutton(''+componentName+'.apply');
```

Now the modal Save button does its thing and then joomla saves the item and knows which component view its saving it to and stays on the page. This allows me to collect the table data but also saves the content within the repeatable fields modal in-case the user thought they were saving it and accidentally clicked close on the default button group of the item.

I hope I can help someone out with my answer/post. If its not appropriate to put all this in just let me know and i'll move it elsewhere.

--

Comment: Great work! If you can you should make a PR with your changes to the staging repo. The functionality you implemented seems like a welcome addition.

Comment: @MathewLenning thanks. Yes but where do i start? im not sure even where to go to submit such things. The joomla forums and repositories seem a bit all over the place. If you can link me or direct me to teh right place i would be happy to create an account and start contributing, i think :)

Comment: It takes a little work to get started contributing, but once you get the hang of it, it is a lot of fun (geeky programmer type fun =^P) Here is a tutorial that should help get you started. http://docs.joomla.org/Git_for_Coders

Comment: nice job! how do you override the original repeatable.js? as you know it's not a good practice to hack the original one.